# Passing Exception error from an outside method to display in the widget tree

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and trying to build an app. I am facing this issue right now and just want to ask how to pass an error message from an outside method to my widget tree and display it there inside an alert dialog? This is my current code as of now:

auth.dart

```
  Future<void> signInUser(String userEmail, String userPassword, errMessage) async {
    try {
      authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: userEmail, password: userPassword);
      print(authResult.user.uid);
    } on PlatformException catch(error) {
      errMessage = 'An error occurred while processing the request. Please check and try again.';
      if(error.message != null) {
        errMessage = error.code.toString();
        print(errMessage);
      }
    }
  }
```

login.dart

```
  String _userEmail = '';
  String _userPassword = '';
  String _sysError = '';

  Auth _auth = new Auth();
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  void onSubmit() {
    if(_signInKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _signInKey.currentState.save();
      _auth.signInUser(_userEmail, _userPassword, _sysError);
      if(_sysError != null) {
        showAlertDialog(_scaffoldKey.currentState.context);
      }
    }
  }
  .
  .
  .
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   ...
   RaisedButton(
     onPressed: onSubmit,
   ),
   ...
  }
```

I hope you can help me resolve this issue. thanks in advance!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                    Future<String> signInUser(String userEmail, String userPassword, errMessage) async {
                    try {
                    authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: 
                    userEmail, password: userPassword);
                    print(authResult.user.uid);
                    return null;
                      } on PlatformException catch(error) {
                    errMessage = 'An error occurred while processing the request. Please check 
                    and try again.';
                    if(error.message != null) {
                      errMessage = error.code.toString();
                      print(errMessage);
                    }

                      return error.message;
                  }
                  }






                    String _userEmail = '';
                     String _userPassword = '';
                    String _sysError = '';

                    Auth _auth = new Auth();
                  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

                      void onSubmit() asysc{
                  if(_signInKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    _signInKey.currentState.save();
                      _sysError =   await  _auth.signInUser(_userEmail, _userPassword, _sysError);
                    if(_sysError != null) {
                      showAlertDialog(_scaffoldKey.currentState.context);
                    }
                      }
                        }

                    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                   ...
                    RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: onSubmit,
                ),
                ...
                }
```

Comment: It works, so basically, I am missing some bit  logic and lines of codes. Btw, You're a lifesaver. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome Jhei Krauzer